# Observable.empty what returns inside a zip?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

If a function returns an Observable.empty(), what i will get after doing a Observable.zip of this value? The problem is that i always want to execute the code inside Observable.zip and since source2() can fail, i do a catchError and then return an empty observable. But i'm unsure if the zip still will call the block with this approax.

```
 func source1() -> Observable<String> {
  return Observable.just("test")
}

func source2() -> Observable<Int> {
  return anObservableThatCanFail()
  .catchError { error -> Observable<Int> 
       return Observable.empty()
  }
}

func myFunc() {
    Observable.zip(source1(), source2()) { string, integer 
   //this will be called despite source2() do a empty()? 
   //and if so, what integer contains?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [reactivex.io](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)'s documentation:

> It applies this function in strict sequence, so the first item emitted by the new Observable will be the result of the function applied to the first item emitted by Observable #1 and the first item emitted by Observable #2; the second item emitted by the new zip-Observable will be the result of the function applied to the second item emitted by Observable #1 and the second item emitted by Observable #2; and so forth. It will only emit as many items as the number of items emitted by the source Observable **that emits the fewest items.**

So in this instance, because `.empty()` will emit 0 item, meaning `zip` will also emit 0 item.

If you really need the zipping function to be executed, you could change the type of `source2()` from `Observable<Int>` to `Observable<Int?>` and, instead of returning `.empty()` from the `catchError` block, return `.just(nil)`.

```
func source2() -> Observable<Int?> {
  return anObservableThatCanFail()
    .map { (result: Int) -> Int? in result }
    .catchError { error -> Observable<Int?> 
       return Observable.just(nil)
    }
}
```